# Sharing a string between classes ruby

Tags: ruby

I have several classes that make requests to a site. For example, one class for scraping `www.example.com/albums`, another for `www.example.com/singles` etc.

```
/lib
   /classes
      /example
        album_request.rb
        singles_request.rb
```

In each of these classes I have a constant defining the external url. e.g.

```
module Example
   class AlbumRequest 
       BASE_URL = 'http://www.example.com/albums'
   end
end
```

This means I'm repeating `example.com` in all my classes. What if the hostname suddenly changes?

I think my code would be better like this:

```
module Example
   class AlbumRequest
      ALBUM_URL = "#{BASE_URL}/albums"
   end
end
```

Where `BASE_URL` is defined somewhere else. Where should I define such a constant? If I define it in a lower level module, am I not breaking the dependency inversion principle? Should I be putting it in a config? (even though I can assume the url will not change)

I also want to share a request header hash between all requests.

```
REQUEST_HEADERS = {
     'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Some application config would be best place for that in my opinion

Comment: application.yml would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about a `MainRequest` class which is inherited by every other class, something like

```
# lib/classes
class MainRequest
  BASE_URL = 'http://www.example.com/albums'

  HEADERS = {
    header1: 'value1',
    header2: 'value2'
  }
end
```

Thus, you can do,

```
module Example
  class AlbumRequest < MainRequest
    ALBUM_URL = "#{BASE_URL}/albums"
  end
end
```

I presume, you might also be repeating the logic of executing requests, because of above code, you can centralize that too and dry up your code a bit.

```
#lib/classes/main_request.rb

def execute_request(url, method = 'GET', params = {})
  # common logic of request and return response where params include headers, body, params
end

module Example
  class AlbumRequest < MainRequest
    ALBUM_URL = "#{BASE_URL}/albums"

    response = execute_request(ALBUM_URL, 'GET', some_params)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if having a base class consisting of nothing but constants is a good idea? Part of the reason of having these subclasses is to encapsulate the internals of the request (url, http verb, params). So for example I can just call `album_request.perform`. I don't think I can share any functionality in the base class

Comment: Ofcourse, it is not a good idea for only constants. That's why suggested you a centralised method for executing requests, which dries up your code. If you can't share any functionality then don't do it...alternately what you can do is write a module say `constants.rb` if you can put it in initializer so that the constant is available​ everywhere(I recommend), well and good. Else `include` it in all the classes.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a go and try to see which method fits best!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ENV file  to manage your app,